# What's the best AWS service to use for a simple database (essentially just a key/value store) shared by a number of different services?

Tags: database, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, serverless, aws-serverless

We have a number of (micro) services, some as simple as a single lambda function, and some are full RDS apps.  One thing that they all need to do is access an foreign ID key mapping.  That is, they all are passed a certain type of ID, but need to included the "name" field associated with that ID in their responses.  Basically, just a key/value store.

I could build a separate microservice to manage these mappings (and maybe still will), but that also needs the simple database.

My services don't usually get a huge amount of throughput, but I need them to be performant.

I'd like to keep it cheap, and I'd like it to be as low maintenance as possible.

Basically, I'd like something "Serverless" (i.e. doesn't require an ongoing EC2 instance or RDS instance running), fast, and straightforward to access.

I've thought about just having each "key" be an S3 key, with the value being the object, but that's not super performant when I need to access a bunch at a time. (should I look into redshift spectrum? is that way overkill?  does it matter if is?)

I know AWS used to offer simpledb, which is probably basically what I'm after.  So what would be closest now?

Thanks for your advice!

Comment: DynamoDB is probably the best fit

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Technically, [SimpleDB still exists](https://aws.amazon.com/simpledb/) in several of the older [regions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html#sdb_region).

But AWS never, ever talks about it.

Even the SimpleDB FAQ seems to say more about DynamoDB than it does about SimpleDB.

> **Q: How does Amazon DynamoDB differ from Amazon SimpleDB? Which should I use?**
>
> Both services are non-relational databases that remove the work of database administration. Amazon DynamoDB focuses on providing seamless scalability and fast, predictable performance. It runs on solid state disks (SSDs) for low-latency response times, and there are no limits on the request capacity or storage size for a given table.
>
> https://aws.amazon.com/simpledb/faqs/

There seems to be little reason to consider anything other than DynamoDB as the "closest thing" to a successor service to SimpleDB -- although admittedly this is somewhat like saying a jet aircraft is the closest thing to a single-engine biplane.  But they are both managed NoSQL databases.

Previously, DynamoDB was priced in a way that made it better-suited to large workloads, but since DynamoDB now supports [per-request pricing](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/amazon-dynamodb-on-demand-no-capacity-planning-and-pay-per-request-pricing/) I don't see any reason this wouldn't be the way to go for the application you describe.  Formerly, DynamoDB required you to subscribe to a certain level of capacity, which was always available but you paid for, whether you needed it and used it, or not.  That option is still there, but per-request looks good for a lot of use cases.  It also supports "global tables," if you want your data automatically replicated to multiple regions for lookup performance.

Comment: Ah, I didn't know about the DynamoDB per-request pricing.  I'd done some research and your jet/biplane analogy was something I'd picked up on, and was giving me pause.  I'll dig into DynamoDB as my solution.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use DynamoDB, RDS or S3, I wouldn't recommend SimpleDB.

As for what's "best" I guess it depends on what are the requirements: "better" or "worse" in what regards? ease of development? latency? availability? regional/multi-region? and etc